# Whatsapp Scraping using the 'whatsapp-web' library

Tags: python, web-scraping, whatsapp

I'm trying to extract all contact names from a specific WhatsApp group using 'whatsapp-web' library. Tried the code given at [link](https://pypi.org/project/whatsapp-web/) to access open chats but got timeout error. Would appreciate some guidance with this task. Thanks in advance!

Comment: code in your link is 2 years old - WhatsApp could change its page many times and now code may not work.

Comment: Other people are having the same issue with that package: https://github.com/Fantaso/whatsapp-web/issues/4.